# Where does Magento 1.6 Store its CMS Page?

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I was looking around the admin panel of magento, and I came across the cms menu, which has a pages section. I was not able to locate that pages listed in this section in Magento's file directory structure.  Where can i find all the cms pages, especially the home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento's pages aren't files on the server.  They're stored in the database.  In the stock installation you'll find their content in the `cms_page` table.

Comment: Thanks Alan ,where can i get good tutorial of magento ,i want to make the basic crud application in magento